# Prevent BibLaTex from suppressing pagination prefix

Tags: biblatex

I am citing a manual that has both section numbers and paragraph numbers. Sometimes, I want to cite an entire section, other times I want to also include a paragraph. For instance, I might type `\cite[1.2.3 \P 4]{entry}` to refer to section 1.2.3, paragraph 4. My expected output is [1, § 1.2.3 ¶ 4], however whenever I specify the paragraph number, the section symbol is suppressed. I suspect the reason why is that BibLaTeX is trying to determine whether the citation is singular or a range, and can't make sense of it.

My .bib file might look like this:

```
@manual{entry,
    pagination = "section",
    title = "Foo Bar",
    url = "http://www.example.com"
}
```

Comment: `biblatex` tests whether or not the postnote argument is something that looks like a page range. `1.2.3` looks page-y enough for `biblatex` and gets the prefix. `1.2.3 \P 4` is not page-y enough, in particular the `\P` makes the contents fail the `\ifnumeral` test. You have two options: (1) Tell `biblatex` to add the pagination prefix manually: `[\pno~1.2.3 \P 4]` or (2) tell `biblatex` to completely ignore `\P` when it test if something is a numeral: `\NumCheckSetup{\def\P{}}`.

Comment: Please add a MWE showing which `biblatex` style you are using.  As standard, it is a `p.` or `pp.` prefix that is added if `biblatex` guesses it is a page range; when the guess is wrong you can write `\cite[\pno~12 \P4]{entry}` for the `p.` case.  I guess your style provides something similar for the sections.

Comment: Please add a complete but [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty much as you suspected. For the page prefix feature `biblatex` determines whether the postnote argument you have supplied is a single numeral (`\ifnumeral`) or a range or list of numerals (`\ifnumerals`) in order to be able to give the correct prefix 'p.' or 'pp.'. But

```
1.2.3 \P 4
```

is neither of those because the `\P` is not recognised as part of a number.

You can trick `biblatex` into thinking `\P` is an acceptable part of a number with

```
\NumCheckSetup{\def\P{}}
```

Then

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\NumCheckSetup{\def\P{}}

\begin{document}
\cite[1.2.3]{sigfridsson}

\cite[1.2.3 \P4]{sigfridsson}

\cite[1.2.3-1.2.4]{sigfridsson}

\cite[1.2.3 \P4-1.2.3 \P5]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: [1, p. 1.2.3]/[1, p. 1.2.3 ¶4]//[1, pp. 1.2.3–1.2.4]//[1, pp. 1.2.3 ¶4–1.2.3 ¶5]]

If this is just a one-off you can add the page prefix manually with `\pno`/`\ppno`:

```
\cite[\pno1.2.3 \P 4]{sigfridsson}
```

Comment: +1 to your crystal ball!